# How to cut metal garage door arm?

Tags: garage-door, metal-cutting

I have a garage door and straight metal arm passes beyond the curved arm. The door of my new car's trunk is too high and I need to cut the end. I do not know what kind of metal it is but I want to cut the end. What should I be using? Do I need power a power tool?

[image: garage door arm]

Comment: An angle grinder with a cutoff wheel. You can get one at Harbor Freight for 15 USD. It'll spit tiny bits of hot stuff, so keep any fancy surfaces out of the line of fire. Don't put your eye out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just regular steel.

If you cut it manually (with a metal saw)  it might take a while.

If you use angle grinder it goes fast.

In case 1 you are permitted to have a beer break, incase 2 not.

Comment: Angle grinders are interesting and sometimes useful toys, but they're also dangerous if not used carefully and a waste of money if only used once.

Comment: Took 5-10 minutes with a saw I had.

Comment: @Supertech you are a fast beer drinker

Comment: I skipped the beer; it was a cold day. For sure I will have one for it when I am in the mood.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest and cheapest solution may be a hacksaw with a metal cutting blade.